# Object disappears in render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I use Blender v2.77 and **Cycles Render**. I have searched for answers, but the solutions didn't help me with my issue. I have one object, which I can see always, but when I choose **render** as display method, it is gone.

Here are 2 screenshots. It concerns the *"SpirulinaEmitter"*.

[image]

[image]

I am a total newbie with Blender, so it might be an easy error. but I am totally stuck right here.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guys, I found the problem. I changed this at the very beginning when I watched a tutorial and of course, forgot about it:

[image]

*The invisible object was a particle emitter. And I unchecked the "Emitter" box under Particles > Render!*

Comment: You can accept your own answer if the problem is solved :)